# Hippocrates trapezoid lune

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

How can I prove that a lune based on the construction of a constructible isosceles is quadrable? 
Hippocrates' other squarable lune

Comment: There is a nice online article in [Cut-the-Knot.](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/FaultyLuneQuadrature.shtml)

Comment: Thanks Andre, yet I can not derive a formal proof from that article.

Comment: There are endlessly many articles on squarable lunes. Unfortunately, writing an answer would be too painful, at least for me, it would take too much time to draw the diagrams.

Comment: I found some but none that use Euclid's Elements on the trapezoid lune.  Can you post some of those articles? Many thanks.

Comment: I really need to know the answer to this too!